# Post to Facebook and twitter when one button?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5, social-networking, facebook-social-plugins

can someone please help me out, how would I connect facebook and twitter up to the same button? So for example someone has written a status update, and with a one button press it sends it both to Facebook and twitter?.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create a service that first connects and authenticates with users Facebook and Twitter account. Once that is done then you can call that service to post the update. Let me expand:

There is a service called IFTTT https://ifttt.com/

What this service does is authenticates both your facebook and twitter account (one by one). Once IFTTT gets the permission, then whenever you post something on any one these accounts, it calls the service and does the same on other account. So, you can create a recipe:

If I post on Facebook, then post on Twitter as well.